# How do I get my CSS divs to "stick" to the same spot on the background image, even when the browser is resized both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css

I essentially want the divs (which are red dots) to stay on the same location on a world map, thus I don't want the divs to move when the browser is resized vertically and horizontally. I'm not sure if I need to be focusing on the div properties or the background's.

Below is my CSS code, ALSO any feedback on my CSS code in general is welcome! I'm new to web design, thanks! :

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>My World</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="home" class="home">
            <div id="dallas" class="box, dallas"></div>
            <div id="hongkong" class="box"> </div>
            <div id="capetown" class="box"></div>
            <div id="seoul" class="box"></div>
            <div id="mumbai" class="box"></div>
            <div id="northampton" class="box"></div>
            <div id="sanfrancisco" class="box"></div>
            <div id="newyork" class="box"></div>
        </div>

    </body>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="interactive.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

And my CSS

```
/*****************
MAIN
******************/
body {
    background: url('worldmap.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;


}

#home {


}

/* Button Design */

.box {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #FE2E64;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-radius: 100%;


}


/*****************
HOME BUTTONS (Placement only)
******************/

.home {
    position: relative;
} 

#dallas {
    margin-left: 22.5%;
    margin-top: 7%;

}

#hongkong {
    margin-left: 81.2%;
    margin-top: 1.5%;

}

#capetown {
    margin-left: 55%;
    margin-top: 15%;

}

#seoul {
    margin-left: 85%;
    margin-top: -22.5%;

}

#mumbai {
    margin-left: 69.5%;
    margin-top: 4.5%;
}

}

#northampton {
    margin-left: 29%;
    margin-top: -8.5%;


}

#sanfrancisco{
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 0%%;

}

#newyork {
    margin-left: 28%;
    margin-top: -2%;
}

/*****************
HOVER 
******************/

#dallas:hover {
    background-color: #F5A9BC;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#hongkong:hover {
    background-color: #F5A9BC;
    cursor: pointer;
}


#capetown:hover {
    background-color: #F5A9BC;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#seoul:hover{
    background-color: #F5A9BC;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mumbai:hover{
    background-color: #F5A9BC;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#northampton:hover {
    background-color: #F5A9BC;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#sanfrancisco:hover {
    background-color: #F5A9BC;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#newyork:hover {
    background-color: #F5A9BC;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your html too, ideally in jsFiddle or similar?

Answer (score 0):

`.home {
    position: relative;
}`
I think you have to make it  position: FIXED

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure they do not move at all you could try

```
position:fixed;
```

This would be in the css for the dots. This would not move the dots anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a fixed width on your `.home` div. Example -

```
.home{
    width: 720px;
}
```